# Windows partition by default created & mounted after installing 16.04 LTS Dell Precision 7510

Tags: partitioning, mount

I noticed right after I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from the USB bootdisk it by default created a partition named OS in one of my harddisks. The contents of this are the following:

[image]

Is this best practice to keep such a partition with the installation files? What would be the impact if I remove this partition? The hard disk partition table looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F34F5B83-47CF-4563-9133-9E25CB22823F

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1026048    7317503   6291456     3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3   7317504  866150399 858832896 409.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p4 866150400 1000214527 134064128  63.9G Linux swap
```

Also notice the 3GB partition is a Windows Fat32 file system. Any reason why the Ubuntu installed this windows File system with Ubuntu image files?

Answer (score 0):

I have a dell laptop, and the default windows partion is called OS. I think this is so your laptop will boot from the partition as maybe the laptop is restricted to only booting from a specific partition. I am proabaly incorrect. It also seems like it has boot files so don't delete it